# Unable to ping the IP during first boot

Tags: ping

I am trying to add some routes in /etc/init.d/S98 script but it is failing to ping the gateway IP and hence route addition is failing. But once all the S98 scripts are executed I am able to ping the IP and add the routes. Below are the logs captured during S98 script execution. Could you please help me in understanding if I am missing something during init script (/etc/rc3.d/S98) execution.

```
PING 27.190.35.1 (27.190.35.1) from 27.190.35.171 bond0.3: 56(84) bytes of data.
From 27.190.35.171 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 27.190.35.171 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 27.190.35.171 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable

# ifconfig 
bond0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B4:B5:2F:59:FF:E8
          inet addr:192.168.1.1  Bcast:192.168.1.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:9000  Metric:1
          RX packets:446 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:290 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:10000
          RX bytes:51268 (50.0 KiB)  TX bytes:42174 (41.1 KiB)

bond0.2   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B4:B5:2F:59:FF:E8
          inet addr:10.63.73.16  Bcast:10.63.73.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:45 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:49 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:10000
          RX bytes:2070 (2.0 KiB)  TX bytes:2058 (2.0 KiB)

bond0.2:1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B4:B5:2F:59:FF:E8
          inet addr:10.63.73.5  Bcast:10.63.73.127  Mask:255.255.255.128
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

bond0.3   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B4:B5:2F:59:FF:E8
          inet addr:27.190.35.171  Bcast:27.190.35.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:39 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:40 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:10000
          RX bytes:1794 (1.7 KiB)  TX bytes:1680 (1.6 KiB)

bond0.3:1 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B4:B5:2F:59:FF:E8
          inet addr:27.190.35.170  Bcast:27.190.35.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1

bond0:1   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B4:B5:2F:59:FF:E8
          inet addr:192.168.1.30  Bcast:192.168.15.255  Mask:255.255.240.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MASTER MULTICAST  MTU:9000  Metric:1

eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B4:B5:2F:59:FF:E8
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:9000  Metric:1
          RX packets:304 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:272 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:10000
          RX bytes:35698 (34.8 KiB)  TX bytes:39596 (38.6 KiB)
          Interrupt:32 Memory:f6000000-f67fffff

eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr B4:B5:2F:59:FF:E8
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING SLAVE MULTICAST  MTU:9000  Metric:1
          RX packets:142 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:10000
          RX bytes:15570 (15.2 KiB)  TX bytes:2578 (2.5 KiB)
          Interrupt:36 Memory:f4800000-f4ffffff

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:156 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:156 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:14528 (14.1 KiB)  TX bytes:14528 (14.1 KiB)

# route
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
10.63.73.0      *               255.255.255.128 U     0      0        0 bond0.2
27.190.35.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 bond0.3
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.240.0   U     0      0        0 bond0
default         10.63.73.126    0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 bond0.2

traceroute result:
traceroute to 27.190.35.1 (27.190.35.1), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  Cage-3-dsc-sb-phy-A (27.190.35.171)  3000.659 ms !H  3000.649 ms !H  3000.634 ms !H

arping result: 
ARPING 27.190.35.1 from 27.190.35.171 bond0.3
```

Comment: You chose a name for your script that makes it look like a stop link.

Comment: First off are you sure you're booting into `runlevel 3`?  Have you made sure that your network comse up before you try applying the routes?  Thirdly are these networks VLANed on the same switch?

Answer (score 0):

The init scripts are run in order of the number in them:

- S01first
- S10tenth

  ...
- S90ninetieth

This is done so you can stack dependancies in services, just like `S85httpd` depends on `S10network`. If there are no dependencies, such as with `S08ip6tables` and `S08iptables`, the order in which the run is not important.

So if you have a dependency on `S98` having been run, which is what read here, you can put the service in `S99`.

*Personally, unless there are good reasons, I would renumber the script just after the range that the network scripts are usually run, just after `S20` or `S30`, depending on what is installed.*

**EDIT:** You might want to change from a custom solution to using the common way of implementing bonding. [Linux Bond / Team Multiple Network Interfaces (NIC) Into a Single Interface](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-bond-or-team-multiple-network-interfaces-nic-into-single-interface.html), and read [Painfully Slow Or No Failed Link Detection](http://www.cyberciti.biz/howto/question/static/linux-ethernet-bonding-driver-howto.php#section_10_3) if you are still experiencing the similar issues.

Comment: I have captured the logs when the issue was faced. Even arping is failing.

Comment: Yes I am booting in runlevel-3 and the script (/etc/rc3.d/S98) is getting executed properly but in the script I am trying to ping the  IP which is failing. You can see that the network services are up and all the IPs are plumbed. I am trying to add a gateway IP to reach the external network which if failing. I tried renaming the script as S99 but still it is failing.

Comment: You don't need to rename the script, you probably need to split the script into 2 parts, and S98 and S99 part.

Comment: I think you misunderstood my query, there is no dependency between S98 and S99 scripts. I am just wondering why ping to external gateway IP is failing during init script execution whereas it is working after some time.

Comment: If I read your question correctly you have a number of tools being run in S98, some of these fail, when on running these after the execution of S98 they succeed. To me that sounds like you should create a new script called S99 which runs these commands.

Answer (score 0):

Check on the switch you have portfast turned on for the ports. Not having portfast means the switch will wait 30 seconds before forwarding packets.

interface FastEthernet1
 spanning-tree portfast